# how to set automatically the size of the x axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Variable x goes from 0 to 19. But I have other examples where it will go from 0 to 28 or from 0 to 5. So, how can I set that to be automatic instead of writing all the numbers as I have done in "plt.xticks"?

```
    for i in range(x.shape[1]): 
        xA=x[:, i].reshape(-1,1)
        skf = StratifiedKFold(y, n_folds=2, shuffle=True)
        scoresSKF = cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, xA, y, cv=skf)

        plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
        plt.xlabel('Features')    
        plt.title('Accuracy by feature: Random Forest')

        plt.xticks([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19], rotation = 'vertical')
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `arange` from numpy: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html

```
import numpy
...
x_ticks = numpy.arange(20) # generate a seq from 0 to 19, step is one.
plt.xticks(x_ticks, rotation = 'vertical')
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy
...
x_ticks = numpy.arange(i+1) #As the loop starts in 1, the plot will be 0->18. So I add 1 because I want the plot 0->19
plt.xticks(x_ticks, rotation = 'vertical')
```